# Is there a way to identify the cause for session expiry?

Tags: asp.net, session

The session time out is set to 20mins but the application session keeps expiring abruptly well within 20 mins. I am not able to identify the cause of session expiry? Is there a way to find what is causing the session expiry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that trips me up every-so-often is changing the directory structure of the site.  For instance, adding/deleting some kind of user-specific folder within the site structure (or any other folder).  This causes a recycle and all sessions are expired.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of this. Does adding/deleting any folder in the site structure trigger an app domain recycle and session expiry? Because, I create and delete a few temp folders in the site structure.

Comment: yip --- this has been my experience.  What I then do is create my temp folders outside of the structure in some temp space.

Comment: Thanks Eben. I guess I found the cause for my problem.